# JQuery/Javascript process question

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-idle

I've inherited someone else's project and am building a work flow diagram for it. Without getting into too many details the person who left was the only person in the web department with advanced programming skills (most people there do production work and some HTML/CSS stuff). The project I inherited was developed in CodeIgniter and leans heavily on JQuery, AJAX and JSON. The flow is a bit confusing hence my outlining it. (I'm getting to the question, bear with me)

Anyway, the manager of this department, let's refer to him as The Tool, won't allow his people to learn any of this stuff. He asked me the other day how it was coming and I said fine except I can't find where one variable is being set, the original developer is using jquery to call some form value to set a path to files (he using #id.val()) but I can't find #id anywhere in the code. The manager replies, eh, I thought you were the PHP guru. As I said, we shall refer to him as The Tool.

Anyway, to stick it to him somewhat I've decided to share these flow pages with people in his group, make them very descriptive and hopefully educational. I'm explaining how when a change is made from a select menu jquery/javascript recognizes that change and fires off related code in JS.

Then it dawned on me that I really didn't know how JS/JQ knew the change had been made. I know the code ($("#id").change()...I have an AppleScript background and in that language there's an idle command, you basically can have a script sit in the background observing and waiting for X to happen (say the user launches Photoshop) and when that event happens the rest of the code is run. Does JS do something similar?

Comment: interesting story. But you question really is `what does $("#id").change() do?` - innit?

Comment: Nah, I know what that does. My question is how does the browser communicate an event happening to js

Comment: @Pruitlgoe the browser "communicates" an event by invoking registered event handlers. The jQuery library (and other frameworks like it) provide a management layer for event handlers, but the basic operations are the same. When an event happens, the browser associates it with a page element and starts looking for registered handler functions.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$("#id").change()
```

tells jQuery (the "$") to find the element whose "id" value is (in this case) "id", and then to trigger a "change" event on the element.  That will cause event handlers registered to look for such events on that element to be run. That's the basis of just about everything you do with JavaScript in a browser: responses to events.

Somewhere, there's probably one of these:

```
$("#id").change(function() { ... })

$("#id").live('change', function() { ... })

$("#id").bind('change', function() { ... })
```

There are many ways for the element to have been identified for setting up the event handlers, however, so it may be tricky to find.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I get how events happen but what connects the HTML elements to the JS? Is there code within the browser app itself that observes the events happening, checks to see if there is a js script associated with the page, that the user has js enabled and then passes the event to the js script? I'm probably not making myself clear. I'll use my AppleScript example again, I can build an application from applescript, all it does is sit on your desktop, idle, waiting for specific event, in this case the opening of Photoshop, in which case it then runs a subroutine to log

Comment: that event to a text file. Think of the AS app as the browser, the opening of Photoshop as an HTML event and the subroutine as some JS...without the idle handler (the app sitting back and watching events on the desktop) this app wouldn't function. I'm thinking a browser functions similarly.

Comment: @Pruitlgoe All those "$(something)" calls are requests into the jQuery library. Not all libraries work like jQuery, but most have some way of "finding" objects in the DOM.  With jQuery, a string passed in to that "$" function (also aliased as "jQuery") is interpreted as a CSS selector (with some extensions to CSS), and the result of that is that the subsequent operations are carried out on all matched elements. Calls to functions named after events are either calls to bind handlers (when a function is passed) or to trigger events.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of chrome you can inspect a html element, and this will also show 'classic' events that are bound to it.

Increasingly good developers are moving to event delegates such as: 
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#delegate

Which will likely not show up in Chrome, but should be readable from the code.